# How do I getReference if the table is inside a key?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to input data into a new folder that's inside a key(forgive me i dont know the real term for it) but everytime i input data with this code

```
if (isset($_POST['TEST']))

{
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    $key_child = $_POST['key_child'];
    $ccode= $_POST['Course_Code'];
    $desc= $_POST['Desc_title'];
    $unit= $_POST['Unit'];
    $prereq= $_POST['Pre-Req'];
    $grade= $_POST['Grade'];

    $addData = [
        'Course_Code' => $ccode,
        'Desc_title' => $desc,
        'Unit' => $unit,    
        'Pre-Req'=> $prereq,
        'Grade' => $grade,
    ];

    $ref_table = 'User/'.$key.'/Grades/1st Year/1st Sem';
    $addData_result = $database->getReference($ref_table)->push($addData);

    if($addData_result)
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Subject Added Successfully";
        header('Location: students.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Subject not addded";
        header('Location: students.php');
    }
}
```

it doesnt get put inside the key but beside the key instead as shown in this image:

[image: screenshot]

I want to find the correct getReference line to add data *inside* the key and not beside it.

Comment: I assume your `$key` is not properly set, resulting in a new object parallel to the `User` object (as your reference will then be something like `/User/Grades/1 st Year/1st Sem`).

Comment: You are welcome :-). Sometimes it's just too easy and gets overlooked quickly.